# Add different delimiters in javascript toString()..?

Tags: javascript, arrays

normally JavaScript’s `toString()` method returns the array in a comma seperated value like this

```
 var myArray = [ 'zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five' ];
 var result = myArray .toString();
```

And it returns the output like this **`zero,one,two,three,four,five`**.

But I have a requirement to represent the result in this format **`zero_one_two_three_four_five`** (replacing the comma with `_`).

I know we can do this using replace method after converting the array to string. Is there a better alternative available?

Cheers

Ramesh Vel

Answer (score 67, accepted):

myArray.join('_') should do what you need.

Comment: thanks edeverett.. i should read the javascript basics first... :(

Comment: No worries, that's what SO is here for. Good thing is the answer didn't take long to write :-)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using `.join();`?

Answer (score 14):

Use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join the elements with a specific separator:

```
myArray.join("_")
```

Answer (score 3):

To serve no other purpose than demonstrate it can be done and answer the title (but not the spirit) of the question asked:

```
<pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
Array.prototype.toStringDefault = Array.prototype.toString;
Array.prototype.toString = function (delim) {
    if ('undefined' === typeof delim) {
        return this.toStringDefault();
    }
    return this.join(delim);
}
var myArray = [ 'zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five' ];
var result1 = myArray.toString('_');
document.writeln(result1);
var result2 = myArray.toString();
document.writeln(result2);
</script>
</pre>
```

I don't recommend doing this. It makes your code more complicated and dependent on the code necessary to extend the functionality of `toString()` on `Array`. Using `Array.join()` is the correct answer, I just wanted to show that JavaScript can be modified to do what was originally asked.

Answer (score 1):

Grant Wagner's answer has utility when an array is multi-dimensional.

take the array

```
[['Mary','Had'],['A','Little'],['lamb', 'and']]
```

If you use the `Array.join('_')` method then the result will be something like:

```
Mary,Had_A,Little_lamb,and
```

as the join method uses the `.toString()` method to assemble each element in the main array and this defaults to using the comma separator.

Changing the `Array.toString()` method would however produce the desired result.

Comment: please don't change Array.toString to something else and risk breaking things elsewhere, if you know your data is going to be this shape then just do myArray.flat().join('_')