# How to split and get selection data from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have array like this in JavaScript

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,"4","12","2",6,7,"4",3,"2"];
```

My questions are

1. How do I split the array to change, (comma) to ";"
2. How do I return the number of strings in the array as well as return total value regardless of variable type.
3. How do I return the average value (regardless of variable type again)

Comment: **My Answers:** **1.** That is possible only when you want the result as string. Use `a.join(';')` **2.** Loop over array, if string -> convert to Number and add it to `sum`. Ex. `a.reduce((sum, el) => sum + Number(el + ''), 0)`

Comment: yup i want the result as a string, so i have to parse the array toString first?

Comment: **My Answers:** **3.** You've sum of all in #2 `var avg = sum / a.length;`

Answer (score 1):

**Answering Question 1**

1.Convert it to a string

```
var x=a.toString();
```

2.Perform a global replace

```
var y= x.replace(/,/g,";");
```

3.This gives you `"1;2;3;4;5;4;12;2;6;7;4;3;2"`

**For Question 2**
Simply use the `a.length` method.This will give you the total number of elements.I'm not sure about the String elements part.

Comment: Converting it to a string and doing a global replace is completely unnecessary.  You can simply use the `.join(separator)` function.

Comment: it works for question 1, thanks.. but for q 2 it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

**Change array separator:**

```
a.join(';');
```

as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398830/add-different-delimiters-in-javascript-tostring)

**Number of strings in array:**

```
var stringCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  if (typeof a[i] === 'string'){
    stringCount++;
  }
}

alert("The number of strings is: " + stringCount);
```

Test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/6c42nugy/2/

**Number of all elements in array:**

```
var entireLength = a.length;
```

**Percentage per type in comparison to whole**

```
var stringPerc = (stringCount)/(stringCount + entireLength)

var otherPerc = (entireLength - stringCount)/(stringCount + entireLength)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `a.join(';');` to convert the array into a string separated by semicolons.

To return the number of strings in the array, simply iterate through it and use `toString.call()` like this:

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
    if (toString.call(a[i]) === '[object String]') total++;
}
```

To simply return the total number of items, you can do `a.length`.

If you want the total value as in all the elements summed, you can do this:

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
    total += parseInt(a[i]);
}
```

If you want the average, just take the code above and do `total / a.length;`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,"4","12","2",6,7,"4",3,"2"], sum = 0, strings = 0;

var joined = a.join(';');
console.log("Joined: " + joined);

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(a[i]);

    if (typeof a[i] === "string") {
        strings++;
    }
}

var avg = sum / a.length;

console.log('Sum: ' + sum);
console.log('Average: ' + avg);
console.log('Strings: ' + strings);
```

And link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kndLn3wb/).

Answer (score 0):

All results in one loop.

0 ... n-4: Data
n-3: Count of all strings
n-2: Sum
n-1: Average

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "4", "12", "2", 6, 7, "4", 3, "2"],
    result = data.concat(data.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        typeof a === 'string' && r[0]++;
        r[1] += +a;
        r[2] = r[1] / i;
        return r;
    }, [0, 0, 0])).join(';');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```